# is bluecloth 2 a drop-in replacement for BlueCloth 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bluecloth

Is bluecloth 2 a drop-in replacement for BlueCloth 1?  We have a rails 2.3 app at the moment which uses the BlueCloth 1 gem; if we change our config to use the newer one, will we need to do anything else, or is that sufficient?